# How to open new tab in popup window

Tags: javascript, popup

I would like to have a button/link in a page with the following behavior:

- On the first click, open a pop-up.
- On later clicks, if the pop-up is still open, open a new tab in pop-up window.

I tried to achieve this with in Firefox, but whatever I do non-first pop-up opens in parent window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your code that you tried to achieve this with?

Comment: Give the popup window a name.

Comment: I did. Actually in pop-up window special global function was prepared to open a new tab, this function was called from parent window. But still new tab opened in parent window.

Comment: @Greg I tried many cases and none of them worked. I don't want to flood this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this can work with browser tab. But you can use javascript to display the contents in a DOM tab i.e. the popup window can display tabs.

I hope it helps.